# How to force import use the pip library instead of conda library?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

The following command shows there are two numpy in my machine.

```
bash-4.2$ conda list numpy
# packages in environment at /app/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
numpy                     1.15.0           py36h1b885b7_0    https://mycompany.intranet/repository/anaconda-main-proxy
numpy-base                1.15.0           py36h3dfced4_0    https://mycompany.intranet/repository/anaconda-main-proxy

bash-4.2$ pip list | grep numpy
numpy (1.19.5)
numpydoc (1.1.0)
```

When import `pandas`, it got the following error.

```
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import (
  File "/app/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    "this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.15.4\n"
ImportError: this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.15.4
your numpy version is 1.15.0.
Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.15.4 to use this pandas version
```

Is it a way to make the `import pandas` use the pip version of numpy, which version is 1.19.5? The conda channel is the company's internal one and the version is old.

Comment: You must use you system's python and not the `conda` version.

Comment: The system's python is v2.7 and I had to use the conda version which is V3.6

Answer (score 0):

You could use another [Conda channel](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html) to install a newer version of `pandas` and `numpy`.

For example, you could use the [`conda-forge` channel](https://conda-forge.org):

```sh
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

Use a new Conda environment and install `pandas` with:

```sh
conda install pandas --channel conda-forge
```

The `conda-forge`'s package information: [`pandas`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pandas) and [`numpy`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/numpy)

---

Or, create and use a [virtual environment using `venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) for Python 3.x or `virtualenv` for Python 2.7, and install all needed packages with `pip`. Example with `venv`:

```sh
cd YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT
python -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install pandas
```

See also: https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments

---

Or, downgrade `pandas` to a version which uses `numpy` 1.15.0.